# Trimming string for directory path

Tags: fortran

I'm trying to create the full path of a file, entering the parent folder in via a `Read` statement:

```
PROGRAM fileTest

  IMPLICIT NONE

  Character(LEN=20) :: dirpath,fullpath

  Write(6,*) 'Enter dir path'
  Read(*,'(a)') dirpath
  dirpath=TRIM(dirpath)
  fullpath=dirpath//'/file.abc'
  print*,fullpath

END PROGRAM fileTest
```

Using gfortran, the code compiles, but entering `/home/chris` results in the final print statement still giving

```
/home/chris         /file.abc
```

(note the 9 characters of whitespace).

How do I get rid of the spurious whitespaces?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because `dirpath` is still a `character(len=20)` variable, so its contents are again padded with spaces after `dirpath=TRIM(dirpath)`. You have to do the trimming like this:

```
fullpath = trim(dirpath)//'/file.abc'
```

**Edit:**
As a demonstration of allocatable strings (see my comment), you should be able to handle arbitrary string length more satisfactorily like such, provided your compiler supports this feature:

```
character(:), allocatable  :: fullpath
character(len=some_length) :: buffer

write(6,*) 'Enter dir path'
read(*,'(a)') buffer
fullpath = trim(buffer) // '/file.abc'
```

The string `fullpath` should be automatically allocated to accommodate the exact length of the right-hand side.

Comment: Thanks - Fortran isn't very intuitive coming from more modern languages..!

Comment: Unfortunately, that is especially true for strings. The newer F2003 ability to automatically (re)allocate character allocatables helps, but not in this precise case where you `read` directly into it (you would have to allocate it first). What might help you there is the module `iso_varying_string`. It defines an allocatable string derived type, overloads existing character procedures/operators and also adds some specific I/O procedures.

Comment: This is correct, but `trim` will only pull entries off the end - I've gotten in the habit of removing them from the front of the string as well by using `trim(adjustl(dirpath))`

Comment: @ChrisW Compare that with the overflows with null terminated strings in C or with complexity with StringBuilder and you will not see it that bad.